# no "Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, " even that cucumber test was executed using "mvn test" command

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, cucumber, pom.xml

Could someone suggest me a solution why when I run the test using command `mvn test` to run the cucumber runner class `ExampleRunnerTest` located in `\src\test\java` it runs but the maven build doesn't recognize it. Like I said the test runs does what it should do but the build still fails.

```
1 Scenarios (←[32m1 passed←[0m)
6 Steps (←[32m6 passed←[0m)
1m36.764s

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 98.777 sec - in BasicTest

Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/main/java/cucumber/feature/Basic.feature", glue = "cucumber/stepDefinition",
    format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber-report.json"})

public class BasicTest {
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the features be something like `classpath:packagename/Basic.feature` ?

Comment: it points to the right feature and the test gets executed, plus in almost all  example of runners that I found online they were pointing to a feature like that

Comment: having the same issues, did you find out the answer to this ?

Comment: @adityaparikh , you can solve that by adding the maven-surefire-plugin in your <build> profile section in pom.xml

Comment: Hey Did you find the solution for this ? I am having same issue

Answer (score 4):

When I had this problem in my Selenium project I realized that I was using junit and TestNG as well. I removed TestNG codes and dependency from pom.xml. This way I only had junit in my project left. Then everything worked like charm, MVN test results showed the correct numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Replica-

```
Rai Gupta is right.
The dependency was an issue for me also. 
I saw too many "Append your runner class with Test, move the runner class into TEST folder" etc.
```

But you are just destroying the whole design and it will end with differently designed framework.

```
JUnit and SureFire plugin need to be aligned. I used 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

AND

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.12.4</version>

However, this came in with a parallel execution problem. I did not need it, removed. But you can try different versions of the above dependency.
```

Lastly, this worked or me: [Tests not running through Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360736/tests-not-running-through-maven)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for it to work for me

1. Like user = BlondCode said remover or comment TestNG dependency from you pom.xml file.
2. Add JUnit vintage engine dependency to pom.xml
3. Add a resources folder where you will store your feature and step definitions packages e.g. = \src\test\java\resources\feature and \src\test\java\resources\step definitions
4. You runner package remains in \src\test\java folder
5. Last but not the least add the below configuration to surefire plugging. See image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be issue with jUnit supprt in surefire lib. I followed this link to fix the issue. 
 It works ! [Why Your JUnit 5 Tests Are Not Running Under Maven](https://springframework.guru/why-your-junit-5-tests-are-not-running-under-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with JUnit 5 by explicitly adding the following plugins in their latest versions:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Version 2.x doesn't work.